# What is the value of the AutomationPeers in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

What is the value of the AutomationPeers in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Automation provides a base class that exposes controls to Microsoft UI Automation. This can be invaluable in constructing automated unit tests that manipulate UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645045(VS.95).aspx)